# How can I perform application/server configuration changes withouth image rebuild on OPENSHIFT?

Tags: openshift

I have an infrastructure with Openshift (containers) Jenkins (build and deploy jobs) Nexus (here I store WAR and JAR files) and GIT (groovy/yaml files).

Imaging I create an image with Tomcat APP server, a WAR file and some JAR files.

What would be the way to do configuration changes (for example in a file inside `/whatever/webapps/app/config/properties.conf` or even `/etc/tomcat/conf/some.conf`) withouth having to rebuild the image?

**Extra info:**

What I want to achieve is configuration management withouth having to rebuild the war and therefore rebuild/redeploy the image. Is the ConfigMap for this use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to given info i understand that you don't want to rebuild the image if only config change requires for the server, But you need to redeploy the service if any config change happens. for such kind of requirements the config should be configured as ENV for **DeploymentConfig** and trigger **ConfigChange** should be configured for same deployment.

Then if you change the configuration of deployment and apply the changes it will trigger the deployment for the service.